# Multiplication function with recursion in Python

Tags: python, function, recursion, multiplication, negation

I need to write the function mult( n, m ) that should output the product of the two integers n and m. I am limited to using addition/subtraction/negation operators, along with recursion.

This is what I have so far:

```
def mult( n, m ):
    if m == 0:
        return 0
    elif m < 0:
        return n - n(m+1)
    else:
        return n + n(m-1)
```

Can someone help me please because I can't figure it out!

Comment: What's your problem? Please give an example of the input and output.

Comment: There's no recursion in the code.

Comment: Note that it's much simpler to handle negative arguments if you notice that `mult(n, m) == -mult(n, -m)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to call `n(m+1)` in your `elif` and `else` block, since you say `n` is an integer, this is the problem, you should be calling `mult()` function recursively sending `n` and `m+1` or `m-1` as parameters.

Another issue is that you should convert the result of `n - mult(n, m+1)` to negative before returning.

Example -

```
...
    return - (n - mult(n, m+1))
else:
    return n + mult(n, m-1)
```

---

Demo with example changes -

```
>>> mult(5,-3)
-15
>>> mult(-10,-3)
30
>>> mult(5,3)
15
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand the problem and the function is working good now!

Answer (score 2):

Multiplication with Recursion in Python:

```
def multiplication(num_a, num_b):
   if num_a == 0 or num_b == 0:
     return 0
   return num_a + multiplication(num_a, num_b - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursion means, you have to call the function itself

```
def mul(a, b):
    def _mul(a, b, c=1):
        if a<c:
            return a, 0
        a, r = _mul(a, b + b, c + c)
        return (a - c, r + b) if a >= c else (a,r)
    return (_mul(a, b) if a<b else _mul(b, a))[1]
```

Comment: This code doesn't work with negative numbers. Just returns 0!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to write in python by using recursion:

```
def mult(a, b):
   if a == 0:
      return 0
   elif a == 1:
      return b
   else:
      return b + mult(a-1, b)
```

Comment: this solution does not work for two negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```py
def mult(a, b):
    if a == 0 or b == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        if a < 0 and b > 0:
            return a + mult(a, b - 1)
        elif a < 0 and b < 0:
            return -b + mult(-a - 1, -b)
        else:
            return b + mult(a - 1, b)
```

Test:

```
def test():
    x1 = mult(5, 3)
    x2 = mult(6, -3)
    x3 = mult(-3, 3)
    x4 = mult(-3, -33)

    print('5 * 3 = ', x1)
    print('6 * -3 = ', x2)
    print('-3 * 3 = ', x3)
    print('3 * -33 = ', x4)

test()
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest code I could think of that accounts for negatives of either number:

```
def prod(m,n):
if n==0 or m==0:
    return 0
elif n<0:
    return -m+prod(m,n+1)
else:
    return m+prod(m,n-1)
```

Answer (score -2):

### multiplication

```
def mul(num1, num2):
  if num1 == 0 or num2 == 0:
    return 0
  return num1 + mul(num1, num2 - 1)
N1=int(input("N1="))

N2=int(input("N2="))
result=mul(N1,N2)
print(result)
```

Comment: lwPlease explain how this is supposed to work for negative numbers (which OP clearly needs covered) and what other advanage your solution has over the existing answers. What additional insight does your post contribute?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review all existing answers before posting a new one.  This is *exactly* the same algorithm, just with different names, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68903011/11810933) from 2.5 years ago.